# Difference between SFT with limited supply and NFTs using Master Edition and Edition accounts

Tags: nft, master-edition, minteditionfrommaster

Can someone explain the difference between an NFT with a Master-edition and edition accounts with a max supply of 1000 and an SFT with a max supply of 1000?

For example, if I were making a platform on which artists could sell 1000 copies of their song (with no meaningful difference between each song copy), which of these should I choose to implement and what are the differences between them? What would cost more to mint/transfer if any difference exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main difference would be that an NFT w/ editions will mint a new unique mint address for each edition. This way somebody could point to their edition and say "They all look the same, but this one is mine." If you did SFT...they'd all look the same and share a common mint address and metadata. So there'd be nothing distinguishable about them.

Ref: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard

Comment: Thanks! So then would I be write in assuming that SFTs would be cheaper than NFTs w/ editions especially at scale? Or is the difference negligible?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct that SFT would be cheaper to mint the collection (until compressed NFTs roll out, any way).

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into compressed NFTs right now and they look interesting. Although they're in alpha I'll look into developing using them and put any updates (links to future posts etc.) as an edit or comment on this post.